# Problems with scan() function in R

Tags: r

I am trying to do a simple process to get values from console with scan()
function in R.

The above R code works well:

```
funent <- function(){
  val <- scan(,,1)
  return(as.character(val))
}

print("Seleccione: 1. consulta, 2.cirugia")
tipo <- funent()
```

But when I add more code below it doesn't work. The  execution doesn't stop in scan.

```
funent <- function(){
  val <- scan(,,1)
  return(as.character(val))
}

print("Seleccione: 1. consulta, 2.cirugia")
tipo <- funent()
while((tipo < 1 | tipo >2 )){
  if (tipo < 1 | tipo >2 ) { 
    print("Introduzca 1(consulta) o 2(cirugia)")
    tipo <- funent()
  }
}
```

Is there anything wrong in my R code?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is wrong with your code. The execution doesn't stop in `scan` because the value of `tipo` is 1 or 2. It works as expected when `tipo` is outside that range:

```
tipo = 0
while((tipo < 1 | tipo >2 )){
   if (tipo < 1 | tipo >2 ) { 
     print("Introduzca 1(consulta) o 2(cirugia)")
     tipo <- funent()
   }
}
[1] "Introduzca 1(consulta) o 2(cirugia)"
1:
```